# Laurel plants are drying up after light trimming. What to do?

Tags: plant-health, dryness

I trimmed the ends of a few branches from my laurel plants (laurus nobilis) this winter (february), and after a couple months, the leaves started to point down , and i can now see them drying up.

It seems they were doing just fine before that. We have seen a lot of rain these past months. The soil is very moist, but not wet. It doesn’t look like it’s affected by insects.

What should I try to bring them back?

I’m in Vancouver, BC. Plant hardiness zone 8b.

[image: potted plants]

[image: closeup]

[image: drainage]